# Configure morphia and mongotemplate

Tags: spring-boot, morphia, mongotemplate

I am trying to configure both morphia and mongotemplate in the same application. I have added the following dependencies in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb.morphia</groupId>
        <artifactId>morphia</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

When I run the application, I get the below error as both dependencies have mongo driver.

> The method's class, com.mongodb.ConnectionString, is available from the following locations:

```
jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.1.1/mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar!/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.class
jar:file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/3.4.0/mongo-java-driver-3.4.0.jar!/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.class
```

> The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

```
com.mongodb.ConnectionString: file:/C:/Users/.m2/repository/org/mongodb/mongodb-driver-core/4.1.1/mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar
```

Removing either one of them gives the following error.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [com.mongodb.MongoClientSettings]

How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try using a modern version of Morphia that uses the 4.0 driver.  You can find the details on the [website](https://morphia.dev).  The current current is 2.2.2 which has seen *many* improvements and updates from 1.3.2.